# Getting two different tables using SQL SELECT in one function width PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want to load in two different variables, one a string a the other an integer, from two different tables in my database using PDO. How can this be achieved? It gives me an error when I try it like this:

```
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("connection data...");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabel1";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        $var1 = $row['integer'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        $var2 = $row['string'];
    }

    print_r (array($var1, $var2));

    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm quite bad at PHP and really new to PDO, so please explain in detail! =)
When searching the web I found that I could probably just do it like this(?): `$query = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table1, table2");` but where do I go from there then?
I also found that you probably could use: `$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);` and then calling the tables like array-names, but I don't really get how...

EDIT

The Error I get here is: "The error is: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach():"

My question is: How can I get two variables from to completely separate tables and print them in the array...?

The tables are not related. it's NOT that I want to load a specif id in one of the tables that I get from another one. The reason I want to load these to variables (that's not related) is that they will be returned to a flash-based app. And I figured it must be a lot less data flowing if you could get the two variables at one and send them back to flash in an array. Then I have no use of using JOIN, right?

EDIT 2:

Okey, apperently I had one of my tables named "values" (table1 and table2 was just an example), and that was forbidden. So now it works fine! =)

Comment: What is the error? Have you considered using a SQL JOIN to combine the two tables into a single result set?

Comment: So…what is your question? This is very vague. You just want to get all the data from two tables?

Comment: Are the two tables related at all?  If they are related, you can use a `Join` statement.  Otherwise, it does not make sense to pull back data from two tables that have no relation in one query.

Comment: The error is: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach():

My question is: How can I get two variables from to completely separate tables and print them in the array...? =)

The tables are not related. it's NOT that I want to load a specif id in one of the tables that I get from another one. The reason I want to load these to variables (that's not related) is that they will be returned to a flash-based app. And I figured it must be a lot less data flowing if you could get the two variables at one and send them back to flash in an array.

Comment: General rule of implementing stuff: Get something built, working and tested in the easiest to understand manner. If someone complains it is too slow then look at making it go faster. So, in your case, i would go with two separate queries initially. Two small problems to solve is easier.